# Running a bash command from a directory

Tags: bash, drupal, drush

I'm encountering an issue where a command (a drush profile, to be exact) needs to be run within a created directory automatically. I can't find much advisement within the script itself running it as an argument, and the logic i've been instructed by my superiors seems to suggest this as the best approach.

Here is what the bash script does:

- It creates the directory structure and some Apache2 files for a Drupal install
- It creates a rudimentary Drush profile that is then used by the utility to
- Autoinstall Drupal and modules by running the alias "standardprofile" within a directory containing this profile file

The actual commands I use to run the script from Bash (full scripts below) are

```
cd /var/www/$DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL
eval "standardprofile"
```

The above lines don't run the script (or anything past the first starting line, and then then bash script resumes) Is there a better way to instruct a bash script to run a command from the specified directory and then resume once any other utilities being run in the foreground finish?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creates the proper staging and development environment for a site

# Init
URL=example.com         #URL used in creating directories
OMIT_STAGING="n"        #Set to true if omitting staging
DOMAINNAME=""

###
# FUNCTIONS
###
function generate_empty_dirs {
    mkdir /var/www/$1-staging.$URL
    mkdir /var/www/$1-dev.$URL
    mkdir /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/logs
    mkdir /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/public_html
    mkdir /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/logs
    mkdir /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/public_html
}

function generate_drupal_staging_apacheconf {
    echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
            ServerName $1-staging.$URL

            DocumentRoot /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/public_html
            <Directory /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/public_html>
                Options -MultiViews +ExecCGI
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=\$1 [L,QSA]

            </Directory>

            LogLevel warn
            ErrorLog /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/logs/error.log
            CustomLog /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/logs/access.log combined
            # enable PHP error logging
            php_flag  log_errors on
            php_value error_log  /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/logs/php_errors.log
            # Possible LogLevel values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
            # alert, emerg.

    </VirtualHost>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1-staging.$URL
}

function generate_drupal_dev_apacheconf {
    echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
            ServerName $1-dev.$URL

            DocumentRoot /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/public_html
            <Directory /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/public_html>
                Options -MultiViews +ExecCGI
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=\$1 [L,QSA]

            </Directory>

            LogLevel warn
            ErrorLog /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/logs/error.log
            CustomLog /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/logs/access.log combined
            # enable PHP error logging
            php_flag  log_errors on
            php_value error_log  /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/logs/php_errors.log
            # Possible LogLevel values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
            # alert, emerg.

    </VirtualHost>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1-dev.$URL
}

function generate_wordpress_staging_apacheconf {
    echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
            ServerName $1-staging.$URL

            DocumentRoot /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/public_html
            <Directory /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/public_html>
                Options -MultiViews +ExecCGI
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

            </Directory>

            LogLevel warn
            ErrorLog /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/logs/error.log
            CustomLog /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/logs/access.log combined
            # enable PHP error logging
            php_flag  log_errors on
            php_value error_log  /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/logs/php_errors.log
            # Possible LogLevel values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
            # alert, emerg.

    </VirtualHost>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1-staging.$URL
}

function generate_wordpress_dev_apacheconf {
    echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
            ServerName $1-dev.$URL

            DocumentRoot /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/public_html
            <Directory /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/public_html>
                Options -MultiViews +ExecCGI
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

            </Directory>

            LogLevel warn
            ErrorLog /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/logs/error.log
            CustomLog /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/logs/access.log combined
            # enable PHP error logging
            php_flag  log_errors on
            php_value error_log  /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/logs/php_errors.log
            # Possible LogLevel values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
            # alert, emerg.

    </VirtualHost>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1-dev.$URL
}

function generate_drupal_drush_dev_profile {
    # Dev
    echo " <?php
    \$db_engine = 'mysql';
    \$db_name = '$1_db';
    \$db_user = '$1_user';
    \$db_pw = '1password';
    \$db_su = 'root';
    \$db_su_pw = '';
    \$site_name = '$1';
    \$account_name = 'admin';
    \$account_pw = 'example';
    \$account_mail = 'example@example.com';
    \$site_mail = \$account_mail;" > /var/www/$1-dev.$URL/installsettings.php
}

function generate_drupal_drush_staging_profile {
    #Staging
    echo " <?php
    \$db_engine = 'mysql';
    \$db_name = '$1_db';
    \$db_user = '$1_user';
    \$db_pw = '1password';
    \$db_su = 'root';
    \$db_su_pw = '';
    \$site_name = '$1';
    \$account_name = 'admin';
    \$account_pw = 'example';
    \$account_mail = 'example@example.com';
    \$site_mail = \$account_mail;" > /var/www/$1-staging.$URL/installsettings.php
}

function alter_group_owner {
    chown -R www-data /var/www/$1-staging.$URL
    chgrp -R www-data /var/www/$1-staging.$URL
    chown -R www-data /var/www/$1-dev.$URL
    chgrp -R www-data /var/www/$1-dev.$URL
    chown -R www-data /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1-staging.$URL
    chgrp -R www-data /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1-staging.$URL
    chown -R www-data /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1-dev.$URL
    chgrp -R www-data /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1-dev.$URL
}

###
# BEGIN MAIN LOGIC
###

# Checks to see if user is Root or is using Sudo, otherwise exit

if [ $(id -u) != 0 ]
then
    echo "You must have elevation to run this script."
    exit 1
fi

# Prompts for name of site
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    read -p "Domain for the new site: " DOMAINNAME

    if [ ! -z $DOMAINNAME ]
    then
        echo "Generating the empty directories now..."
        generate_empty_dirs $DOMAINNAME
    else
        echo "You must provide a valid domain name"
        exit 1
    fi
else
    generate_empty_dirs $1
    DOMAINNAME=$1
fi

# Determine the kind of site being generated
read -p "Is this a (D)rupal or a (W)ordPress site? " SITETYPE
read -p "Do you need both the dev and staging sites? [Y/N] (case sensitive): " NEEDDIRS

    if [ -n "$SITETYPE" ]
    then
        if [ "$SITETYPE" == "D" ]
        then
            generate_drupal_dev_apacheconf $DOMAINNAME
            generate_drupal_drush_dev_profile $DOMAINNAME

            rm /var/www/$DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL/public_html
            rm /var/www/$DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL/logs

            cd /var/www/$DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL
            eval "standardprofile"

            if [ "$NEEDDIRS" == "Y" ] 
            then
                generate_drupal_staging_apacheconf $DOMAINNAME
                generate_drupal_drush_staging_profile $DOMAINNAME
                cd /var/www/$DOMAINNAME-staging.$URL
                eval "standardprofile"
                OMIT_STAGING="n"
            else
                OMIT_STAGING="y"
            fi
        elif [ "$SITETYPE" == "W" ]
        then
            generate_wordpress_dev_apacheconf $DOMAINNAME
            if [ "$NEEDDIRS" == "Y" ] 
            then
                generate_wordpress_staging_apacheconf $DOMAINNAME
                OMIT_STAGING="n"
            else
                OMIT_STAGING="y"
            fi
        else 
            echo "Invalid option provided"
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo "No option provided"
        exit 1 
    fi

alter_group_owner $DOMAINNAME

# Load the new confs into Apache

if [ "$OMIT_STAGING" == "y" ]
then
    a2ensite $DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL
    rm -rf /var/www/$DOMAINNAME-staging.$URL
else
    a2ensite $DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL
    a2ensite $DOMAINNAME-staging.$URL
fi

# Reload apache
service apache2 reload

# All done

echo "Sites created at domains:"
if [ "$OMIT_STAGING" == "y" ]
then
    echo $DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL
else
    echo $DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL
    echo $DOMAINNAME-staging.$URL
fi

exit
#End of script
```

And the drush script

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush
$a = drush_get_arguments();
$current_directory = getcwd();
$profiles = substr($a[1], 0, strlen($a[1])-15) . 'standard.make';
if(file_exists($current_directory . '/installsettings.php')) {
  require_once($current_directory . '/installsettings.php');
}
drush_print("Time to prepare our site install...");

if(!file_exists('logs')) {
  drush_op_system('mkdir logs');
}

if(!file_exists('public_html')) {
  $prev = drush_get_context('DRUSH_AFFIRMATIVE');
  drush_set_context('DRUSH_AFFIRMATIVE', TRUE);
  drush_invoke('make', array($profiles, 'public_html'));
  drush_op_system('cp public_html/sites/all/modules/services/servers/rest_server/lib/spyc/spyc.php public_html/sites/all/modules/services/servers/rest_server/lib/spyc.php');
  #drush_shell_exec('cd public_html');
  #shell_exec('cd public_html');
  chdir('public_html');
  drush_invoke_process("@self","site-install",null,array(
    'db-url' => $db_engine . "://" . $db_user . ":" . $db_pw . "@localhost/" . $db_name,
    'account-name' => $account_name,
    'account-pass' => $account_pw,
    'account-email' => $account_mail,
    'db-su' => $db_su,
    'db-su-pw' => $db_su_pw,
    'site-mail' => $site_mail,
    'site-name' => $site_name,
    'clean-url' => FALSE,
  ));
    drush_invoke_process("@self","pm-enable",
        array('ctools', 'views', 'views_ui', 'features', 'strongarm', 'fe_block',
            'entity', 'token', 'module_filter', 'pathauto', 'devel', 'simplehtmldom',
            'services', 'rest_server', 'entity_token', 'date', 'date_api', 'date_tools',
            'date_views', 'date_popup','rules', 'rules_admin', 'views_slideshow',
            'views_slideshow_cycle', 'strongarm', 'diff', 'auto_nodetitle', 'libraries',
            'realname', 'views_php'),
        array('root' => $current_directory . '/public_html'));
  drush_set_context('DRUSH_AFFIRMATIVE', $prev);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is there a better way to instruct a bash script to run a command from the specified directory and then resume once any other utilities being run in the foreground finish?*

Sure:

```
( cd $dir && cmd )
```

will run cmd from the specified directory.  Since the two commands are run in a subshell, the script will resume in its present directory when the subshell completes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```sh
cd /var/www/$DOMAINNAME-dev.$URL
/usr/bin/env drush "standardprofile"
```